How i can update com.google.android.play:core1.10.2 Maven dependency to an android 14 compatable version
enter image description here
I am facing this issue when i update my games max api to 34 and Inapp version according to google policy but when i update these tring to upload and got this error from googlePlay Console
tried different version of google mobile ads , different version of inapps
